# C: After installing ncurses library compiling a hello world program gets me errors from clang

Tags: c, ncurses

I am quite new to the C programming language.
I am interested in the ncurses library to create TUI's using C.
So I informed myself about it. If found [this site](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/intro.html) that looked like a good starting point. I followed the installation instructions and installed it manually (I wasn't using rpm). No errors. Everything was fine.
Then I was trying to use it and wrote a hello world ncurses program in C:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
  initscr();
  raw();
  printw("Hello World!");
  getch();
  endwin();

  return 0;
}
```

When I was trying to compile it like this:

```
gcc -o test test.c -lncurses
```

it gives me this error:

> ld: can't open output file for writing: test, errno=21 for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your question? What errors do you get? How and where did you installe ncurses? What platform (OS) are you on? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am sorry i accidentally posted it before finishing it........

Comment: Error 21 is `EISDIR` meaning "Is a directory.  An attempt was made to open a directory with write mode specified." (See e.g. [this OSX reference](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/intro.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/intro)). That means you have a *directory* called `test`. Also, calling your executable `test` is usually a bad choice since there is a *command* named `test` as well. Try calling the executable something else.

Comment: Thank you! It's working now!